# DIV height can't be resized with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I want to resize the height of a div element with JavaScript.

From this div, i'm reading the height

```
<div class="pages" id="alles">
```

This is my div i'l want to resize (this can be more than one)

```
<div class="content-block" name="maxhoehe">
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var sh = document.getElementById("alles").offsetHeight;
         document.getElementsByName("maxhoehe").style.height = sh-180 + "px";
```

In chrome, i'l get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined
```

I don't no why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Document#getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) method returns a collection of elements so you need to get the first element by its index otherwise `style` property would be `undefined`( nodelist doesn't have any style property ).

```
document.getElementsByName("maxhoehe")[0].style.height = (sh - 180) + "px";
```

---

To update all, iterate over the elements and update the property.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("maxhoehe");

// in latest browser use Array.from(elements)
[].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(ele){
   ele.style.height = (sh - 180) + "px"
});
```

Comment: Looks great. Thanks. But only the first div will be resized. Not the other ones..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **JQuery** use the code below.

```js
$('#change').on('click', function(){
  $('.content-block').height($('.pages').height());
});
```

```css
div{
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pages" id="alles">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div class="content-block" name="maxhoehe">sad</div>
<input type="button" value="change" id="change" >
```